# Custom Javascript Not Loading On Paginated Pages (Except First Page)

Tags: views, javascript, paging

I am running the following jQuery that affects elements on a page view.

```
$(document).ready(function($){                    
    $(".views-field-field-video").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find("a.cboxElement").click();
    }); 
});
```

The code works perfectly, but only on the first page. When I use the pager at the bottom and navigate to any other page, the script does not work. Then, when I navigate back to the first page, the script also fails.

If I reload the page however, it brings me back to the first page and the script works again.

EDIT: The classes I am selecting in the script remains the same on all pages.

Comment: how is the JavaScript file added and where is it added ??

Comment: It is added through a .js file, and linked in between the  `<head>` `</head>` tags using `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://source_to_file"></script>` It is loading, I can see in the web developer tool.

Comment: Is it added to any tpl file ??

Comment: It is not, but it is loading on the affected pages in the `<head>`.

Comment: Turns out I just needed to turn off AJAX on the view. Sorry for complicating things, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when using ajax pagination in the view, document.ready isn't called.

Instead you should follow best practice and use Drupal.behaviors instead.

That way, the behavior will run on document.ready and on the ajax refresh.

Try this:

```
(function ($) {

  Drupal.behaviors.cboxClick = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $(".views-field-field-video").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find("a.cboxElement").click();
      }); 
    }
  };

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function($){                    
    $(".views-field-field-video").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find("a.cboxElement").click();
    }); 
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Or

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){                    
  jQuery(".views-field-field-video").click(function() {
      jQuery(this).parent().find("a.cboxElement").click();
  }); 
});
```

... May fix your problem.  There could be a fix on your normal pages that converts $ to jQuery, but not in the pagination.  Conspiracy theory, but considering you're using $ in your snippet above I think it's the first place to look.

http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#javascript_compatibility

> JavaScript should be made compatible with libraries other than jQuery
>   by adding a small wrapper around your existing code:
>
> (function ($) {   // Original JavaScript code. })(jQuery);
>
> This wrapper is an anonymous closure that provides state throughout
>   the page's lifetime and ensures your code does not unintentionally
>   create/override global variables.
>
> It also explicitly imports the global jQuery variable so that your
>   code can use the local $ variable instead of the jQuery global. This
>   is essential because Drupal loads jQuery with noConflict()
>   compatibility so the jQuery library does not setup the normal $ as a
>   global variable.

Comment: I do have the whole script wrapped in
`(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) { })(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);`, but I will try the above too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this while looking for a related topic. I noticed that there was only one upvote. I case that was due to it not solving the issue I've just been working on this problem and this is the solution that worked for me:

Given you're already using jQuery (I'm assuming the latest version) the function you're after would be on().

http://api.jquery.com/on/

What on() does is dynamically update the DOM with any functionality you ask for even after new elements are added via ajax or basic JS.

```
$(document).ready(function($){
  // Attach our function to the click behaviour of all current and future
  // .views-field-field-video elements.
  $(".views-field-field-video").on('click', function() {
    // I'm assuming your original path for this was correct
    $(this).parent().find("a.cboxElement").click();
  }); 
});
```

With this approach whenever a new ".views-field-field-video" element is added to the DOM the click behaviour will trigger the function that is attached to it.